# Run synchronize method in netty client

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have a netty socket client. from that client I must first send login and password and wait the answer from server and IF and only IF it success I can continue the job. Is there any way to run login method in syncronize way? this is my client code:

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    .handler(new TRSClientInterfaceInitializer());

    Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
    ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;

    lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("username-password" + "\n");
    ch.closeFuture().sync();

    if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
           lastWriteFuture.sync();
    }
```

Comment: what exactly you mean by success? Successful sending the message or successful login?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom channel handler that extends the SimpleChannelInboundHandler and you will be able to override the channelActive where you could send the authentication info to the server. In the channelRead0 you could verify that you have a valid response and choose to either close the channel if the auth failed . Your handler could look like this

```
 public class AuthHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>{

  @Override
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
     /// send your auth data to the server
  }

  @Override
  public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
    ///verify if you received a valid auth confirm from server if not close the channel
   // you will need to invoke the fireChannelRead if its a valid post authentication data so that the messages can continue in the pipeline.
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'll try it and response u. tnx

Comment: It's not working for me. I opened another task in stack, if u can, please. tnx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280898/check-login-in-blocking-mode-in-netty