# Check login in blocking mode in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, io, netty

I have a simple netty client (socket). every time when I send data to server, I must check is client is logged in or not. If not, I must send user credentials and wait response from server with true or false. but I must do it in blocking mode and if I receive true from server, I can continue sending other data. 
my current code is:

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();   
try {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .handler(new TRSClientInterfaceInitializer());

    Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
    ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;

    for (Message message : list) {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("loginpassword");
        }
        //if login is success, I must loop through all data in list and send other data to server
        lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString);
    }

    if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
        lastWriteFuture.sync();
    }
} catch ////
```

this is my handler:

```
//handler extended from SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String>
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String data) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.flush();
    if ("success".equals(data)) {
        isLoggedIn = true
    }
}
```

How I can implement this logic in blocking mode? I can't find any solution in web. Any help? Pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blocking client until write operation finish:

```
lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString);
lastWriteFuture.await();
```

your server may write some response to indicate whether the request is successful:

```
//handler extended from SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String>
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String data) throws  Exception {
  System.out.println(data);
  System.out.flush();
  if ("success".equals(data)) {
    isLoggedIn = true
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("success!");
    return;
  }
  ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("fail!");
}
```

handle server's response in your **TRSClientInterfaceInitializer** handler.

Comment: I must write it lastWriteFuture.await(); after lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString); or after lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("loginpassword");

Comment: simple and great solution. tnx.